# Can frames without motion be removed automatically in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe

I've created a "time lapse video" where much of the footage is essentially just a static image. Is there a way to automatically remove all frames but the ones that are changed?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a job for premiere. Processing or openFrameworks might be the go.

Comment: Or ffmpeg with one of the decimate filters.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf
"select='if(gt(scene,0.01),st(1,t),lte(t-ld(1),1))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB"
trimmed.mp4
```

You can do it with FFMPEG. The standard mpeg command line tool.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966394/how-to-simply-remove-duplicate-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg